# my layout not align properly is go out of layout

Tags: android

below is my layout which ontain 5 butons i want to show button with equal width and height also margin of internal layout on top and below willbe same but screen show out of layout see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFbg3.jpg i want to show my 5 buttons with eqal space form top and botton for all size screens but my screen show out of layout check it

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutbordercolor" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnback"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bitmap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:src="@drawable/logostar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:text="San Diego Unified"
                android:textColor="#603311"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
                android:textColor="#603311"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/options1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/farmtoschool"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/farm_to_school" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/takeasurvey"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/take_a_survey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share_this_app" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: seelast button sharethis app button is not align properly touch layout bottom

Comment: use relative layout and use margin-top, margin-left, margin-right attributte of imageview to achive this.

Comment: how??? plz edit my code

Comment: i have posted it as answer,check it out

Answer (score 0):

try This....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#E5E5E5"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutbordercolor" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:src="@drawable/logostar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:text="San Diego Unified"
            android:textColor="#603311"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
            android:textColor="#603311"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/twitter"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/farmtoschool"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/farm_to_school" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/takeasurvey"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/take_a_survey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/share_this_app" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you an example and you try to implement this

```
    <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/rl1">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="click"/>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txt1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
             android:text=" some text here" />



         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/abc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="Arial" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/abc2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/abc"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="Arial" />
         </RelativeLayout>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:text="Button" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Always try to reduce the no of layouts inside a single layout. So  to use `RelativeLayout` which is more customizable than others for any requirements

Answer (score -1):

Use padding like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="your_size"

    android:background="#E5E5E5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

This should works.